# Unable to access java.sql.DatabaseMetaData

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to make Hibernate project using maven but after running the application, it is giving me below error :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access java.sql.DatabaseMetaData to determine appropriate Dialect to use
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.x.student.impl.StudentApp.<init>(StudentApp.java:20)
    at com.x.student.impl.StudentApp.main(StudentApp.java:33)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access java.sql.DatabaseMetaData to determine appropriate Dialect to use
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2836)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2832)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)
    at com.x.student.impl.StudentApp.<init>(StudentApp.java:16)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported feature
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwUnsupportedFeatureSqlException(DBError.java:689)
    at oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion(OracleDatabaseMetaData.java:4442)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.resolver.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:130)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: My pom.xml looks like :

Comment: is your database running?

Comment: also can you add hibernate config

Comment: <repositories>
 <repository>
  <id>JBoss repository</id>
 <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories> 
 <dependencies><dependency>
 <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
 <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
 <version>11.2.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javassist</groupId>
   <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
   <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>

Comment: Hibernate.cfg.xml looks like

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">
   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  </property>
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">
   jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
  </property>
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.dialect">
   org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
  </property>

Comment: <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">
   hr
  </property>
  <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
   hr
  </property>
  <property name = "show_sql">
   true
  </property>
  <mapping resource="student.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

Comment: My database is up and running still it gives me this error.

Comment: maybe its better to edit your question add the file contents there:) Also after your edit please make sure question is clean